# I am unable to update the global dict in python in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing

I am unable to update the global dict in python in multiprocessing, the output is {}. What could I do wrong in the code? I intend to print out the updated dict fruits.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
    
fruits ={}
    
def work():
        global fruits
        fruits["Apple"]="{'color':'Red','origin':'Germany'}"
              
if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = mp.Process(target=work)
    p.start()    
    time.sleep(2)
    print(fruits)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `work` runs, it is executing in its own address space and global variable `fruits` that it sees is not the same global variable `fruits` that the main process sees. The simplest solution is to pass to `work` a *managed dictionary* that is sharable across processes. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=dict#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager).

You should also not rely on using a timer in your main process to ensure that the dictionary has been updated. Instead, call method `join` on the `multiprocessing.Process` instances. This will cause the main process to block until the subprocess has completed:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp


def work(fruits):
    fruits["Apple"]="{'color': 'Red', 'origin':'Germany'}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        fruits = manager.dict()
        p = mp.Process(target=work, args=(fruits,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print(fruits)
```

Prints:

```None
{'Apple': "{'color': 'Red', 'origin':'Germany'}"}
```